# What would be the best way to change the timeout depending on the file size when trying to delete it

Tags: c#, io

I want to make sure the file I'm moving doesn't exist at it's destination. This is what I'm doing

```
        // delete if exists already
        if (File.Exists(target))
        {
            File.Delete(target);
        }

        // move to target
        File.Move(source, target);
```

But sometime, the file is not completely deleted when the program hit File.Move. To fix this I'm planning on using a FileSystemWatcher to resume the flow after the file have been successfully deleted. But I don't want to wait for ever so i want to put a timeout on the FileSystemWatcher so that after a while it resume the flow even if the file is not deleted.

I would like to make that timeout a function of the size of the file. So let's say if the file is 1MB, the timeout would be 1 second but if it was 10MB it would be 10 second. Does anybody now the best way to choose this timeout or should I just use a fixed timeout what ever the size of the file.

Comment: `planning on using a FileSystemWatcher`: now you have two problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the other way around:

```
// passing true as the 3rd param to Copy() causes it to overwrite the target file
File.Copy(source, target, true);
File.Delete(source);
```

(If there were a `File.Move(string, string, bool)`, I'd say use that, but there isn't.)

Comment: Here i have the same problem, if the file I'm trying to copy is too big, it will try to delete the source before the copy is finish. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jack, I don't understand. `File.Copy` is synchronous, and won't continue until the copy has completely finished. So the source won't be deleted until the copy has completed, no matter what. If your problem is that you'd like the file copy operation to time out if it takes too long, then you probably need to create an asynchronous wrapper for File.Copy, since I don't believe that the .NET framework provides one.

Comment: The msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) says "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe." so even File.Move should be synchronous. It probably means that the problem is not where I thought it was. I'll try your solution and see if I can make it bug again. Thank you

Comment: I would highly recommend that you compare attributes of the source and destination file for the few occasions when a move is necessary.  For example: you're automating a process where large files are moved around in a batch an a failure of the batch causes the process to end.  On a re-run you simply check source and destination and only move if they are not the same or the destination does not exist.  This could save time under certain scenarios.